# Getting "method saveas of object _workbook failed" error while trying to save an XLSM as CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, runtime-error, save-as

I'm trying to save a macro-enabled Excel workbook as a csv file, overwriting the old one (below I had to change the name of the folder and the Sheet, but that doesn't seem to be the issue).

```
 Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

 Dim SaveToDirectory As String
 Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
 Dim CurrentFormat As Long

 CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
 SaveToDirectory = "\MyFolder\"

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

 Sheets("My_Sheet").Copy

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "My_Sheet" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
 ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 ThisWorkbook.Activate

 ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True

 End Sub
```

Sometimes it fails with

> Runtime Error 1004: method saveas of object _workbook failed**)

The debugger points out:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "My_Sheet" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

I googled and some of the solutions I tried were:

- Specifiying that the directory is a string
- Avoid any special character in the file name or folder (seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364007/save-as-failed-excel-vba))
- Copy paste the worksheet as value before saving it as .csv (seen [here](http://blogs.office.com/2009/07/07/use-the-vba-saveas-method-in-excel-2007/))
- Specifying the FileFormat with the .csv code number (seen [here](http://blogs.office.com/2009/07/07/use-the-vba-saveas-method-in-excel-2007/))
- Disabling/Re-enabling some of the alerts
- Adding other fields in the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs row, regarding passwords, creating backups etcetc

Still, it might run correctly up to 50-60 times in a row, and then at some point fail again.

Any suggestion, except stop using VBA/Excel for this task, which will happen soon, but I can't for now.

**EDIT: Solved thanks to Degustaf suggestion. I made only two changes to Degustaf's suggested code:**

- `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` instead of `CurrentWorkbook.Sheets`
- `FileFormat:=6` instead of `FileFormat:=xlCSV` (apparently is more robust
  to different versions of Excel)

---

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim SaveToDirectory As String
Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
Dim TempWB As Workbook

Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
SaveToDirectory = "\\MyFolder\"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").Copy Before:=TempWB.Sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "My_Sheet" & ".csv", FileFormat:=6
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Guys, thanks to both of you for your replies. I don't have time trying doing this right now, will do tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: I can't vote up both of you due to my rep level, anyway thanks for your help. Degustaf solution looks like it did the trick! I tested it over 100 time and it's not failing. I added on the question above the edited and readapted code from Degustaf reply.

For some reason JMMach was still causing the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally find that `ActiveWorkbook` is the problem in these cases.  By that I mean that somehow you don't have that workbook (or any other) selected, and Excel doesn't know what to do.  Unfortunately, since `copy` doesn't return anything (the copied worksheet would be nice), this is a standard way of approaching this problem.

So, we can approach this as how can we copy this sheet to a new workbook, and get a reference to that workbook.  What we can do is create the new workbook, and then copy the sheet:

```
Dim wkbk as Workbook

Set Wkbk = Workbooks.Add
CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").Copy Before:=Wkbk.Sheets(1)
Wkbk.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "My_Sheet" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Wkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Or, there is an even better approach in a situation like this: `WorkSheet` supports the `SaveAs` method.  No copy necessary.

```
CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("My_Sheet").SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & "My_Sheet" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

I will warn you to resave the workbook to its original name afterwards, if it is staying open, but you already have that in your code.

Answer (score 4):

This is a year old, but I'll add something for future readers

You won’t find a lot of documentation in Excel help for Run-time error 1004 as Microsoft doesn't consider it to be an Excel error.

The answers above are 100% valid but sometimes it helps to know what is causing the problem so you can avoid it, fix it earlier or fix it more easily.

The fact that this is an intermittent fault, and it is fixed by saving with the full path and file name tells me that either your macro may be trying to save an .xlsb file to the autorecover directory after an auto file recovery.

Alternatively, you may have edited the file's path or filename yourself.

You can check the path and filename with:-
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.FullName

You should see something like this in the message box.

C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\DIARY(version 1).xlxb

If so the solution is (as stated above by others) to save your file to its correct path and file name.  This can be done with VBA or manually.

I am now in the habit of manually saving the file with its correct path and filename as a matter of course after any autorecover action as it takes seconds and I find it quicker (if this is not a daily occurrence).  Thus, the macros will not encounter this fault you run it.  Remember that while my habit of manually saving .xlxb files to .xlsm files immediately after a recovery won't help a novice that you give the worksheet to.

### A note on Hyperlinks

After this error: If you have hyperlinks in your worksheet created with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in all likelihood, you will have something like "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\", "\AppData\Roaming\", "../../AppData/Roaming/"or "....\My documents\My documents\" in multiple hyperlinks after file recovery.  You can avoid these by attaching your hyperlinks to a text box or generating them with the HYPERLINK function.

Identifying and Repairing them is a little more complicated

First, examine the hyperlinks and determine the erroneous strings and the correct string for each error.  Over time, I have found several.

Excel doesn't provide a facility in the 'Go To Special' menu to search for hyperlinks created with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.

You can automate the identification of erroneous hyperlinks in a helper column, say column Z and using the formula

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Roaming", Link2Text($C2),1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Roaming", Link2Text($D2),1)))
```

where Link2Text is the UDF

Function Link2Text(rng As Range) As String
    ' DO NOT deactivate.
    ' Locates hyperlinks containing 'roaming' in column Z.

```
' Identify affected hyperlinks
    If rng(1).Hyperlinks.Count Then
    Link2Text = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    End If

  End Function
```

My VBA to correct the errors is as follows

Sub Replace_roaming()

' Select the correct sheet
    Sheets("DIARY").Select

```
Dim hl As Hyperlink
For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\", "")
Next
    For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "AppData\Roaming\", "")
Next

    For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "../../AppData/Roaming/", "..\..\My documents\")
Next
    For Each hl In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, "..\..\My documents\My documents\", "..\..\My documents\")
Next

Application.Run "Recalc_BT"

' Move down one active row to get off the heading
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

' Check active row location
    If ActiveCell.Row = 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If

' Recalc active row
   ActiveCell.EntireRow.Calculate

' Notify
    MsgBox "Replace roaming is now complete."

End Sub
```

I also recommend you get in the habit of doing regular backups and not relying on autorecover alone.  If it fails, you have nothing since your last full backup.

While the worksheet is being fragile backup often, like every hour or after any significant import of new data.

The following shortcuts will backup your worksheet in seconds:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, [highlight the filename], <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, [ X ].  Regular backups allow you to go immediately to your most recent backup without having to restore from last night's backup file especially if you have to make a request of another person to do this.

Comment: Thanks Mike, much appreciated even now!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since the last answer here, but I want to share my experience from today:

After weeks of reliable operation, I ran into the same error all of a sudden without having anything changed in the code section where the workbook is saved.

Thanks to the previous answers I updated my saveas statement from a simple

```
wb.saveas strfilename
```

to

```
wb.saveas Filename:=strfilename, Fileformat:= xlWorkbookDefault
```

et voilà: it worked again.

Sometimes the Microsoft applications behave really strange...

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the Path and the CSV file name into a string variable and drop the .csv; that is handled by the FileFormat. Path must be absolute starting with a drive letter or Server Name:
    `Dim strFullFileName as String`
    `strFullFileName = "C:\My Folder\My_Sheet"`
If on a Server then it would look something like this:
    `strFullFileName = "\\ServerName\ShareName\My Folder\My_Sheet"`
Substiture ServerName with your Server name and substitute ShareName with the your network Share name e.g. `\\data101\Accounting\My Folder\My_Sheet`
    `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullFileName,FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue however for me the problem was I was creating the Filename based on strings extracted from a workbook and sometimes these strings would have characters that can't be in a filename.
Removing these characters did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me there was an issue with not all formulas being calculated, despite having it on "Automatic". I pressed calculate on the bottom left 100 times and then it magically worked.