# Error 1004 when trying to use .SaveAs into C:\Users\Me\ProjectOutput

Tags: vb.net

If `Excel_Default_Path` is set to *C:\ProjectOutput* the following code works perfectly. But if `Excel_Default_Path` is set to *C:\Users\Me\ProjectOutput* it fails with a **1004 error**. Also, the `appExcel` object has no problem at all reading from that same directory in either case.

The `DefaultOutputFilename` is set to *AA1FS-7_VE8GUS_ED.xls* and `fmt` is getting the correct type. Just putting it into the User directory is a problem though.

A little more info. If I quit out of the VB app and select the open Excel app. I can directly save the modified workbook to `C:\Users\Me\ProjectOutput` with no problem at all.

Also, this error occurs on my machine, as well as another machine. The other machine `Excel_Default_Path` is set to *C:\Users\JSS\ProjectOutput*

```
    Dim fmt As Excel.XlFileFormat = GetExcelFileFormatForExtension(fi)
    appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(CStr(Excel_Default_Path & "\" & DefaultOutputFileName), fmt)
```

Comment: Sounds like the application doesn't have write privileges to your folder. Check that first.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. I am logged in as me, with administrator privs. The Security properties of the C:\Users\Me\ProjectOutput are Full Control for all users. This is running on Windows 7 Pro 64.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. *Why does this fail* contains zero relevant information, and that it's a VB question is clear from the vb.net tag you added. Your title should give information about the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will convey information to a future reader here who finds it in a search result.

Comment: An executable does not necessarily have the same privs you have. Try "Run as administrator" to see if that makes a difference. It's not a web application, is it?

Comment: It's not a web app. I ran it as Administrator, but no change.

Comment: Can you go to that folder and create a file by yourself ? Like right-click->New->Text Document ? Sometimes user folders are locked weird ways, even for the admin.

Comment: Yes. Creating a new text file with the right-click in the C:\Users\Me\ProjectOutput has no problem at all.

Comment: See this link - it may be your solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967762/getting-method-saveas-of-object-workbook-failed-error-while-trying-to-save-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The `Excel_Default_Path` actually had a trailing "\" at the end. So that caused the 1004 error. Removing the \ from the variable fixed it.